# my cat had pyometra, treated with medication. 2months since then - she's pregnant now

Tags: cats, infections, neutering, pregnancy

so im from a third world country and we have lots of strays around. i look after two of them, one was diagnosed with pyometra, i consulted with a not-so-experienced vet online, and got suggested some meds. completed the course and she got fine.

its been 2 months since then and she's 1 month pregnant now (assuming).

is this a good news? i mean what're the chances of her having pyometra again? if it happens, will medication alone be enough? bc i dont come from a well-off family :((

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! What medication did the cat get? What did you observe that let you think she is pregnant?